# EC2 instances connecting to lambda result in ConnectFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to access lambda functions from a Windows VM I have created in EC2 for dev purposes but even a simple 'list functions' command fails to connect

I have tried using the AWS CLI through PowerShell, the dotnet sdk and the VS AWS Toolkit but each of these times out after a long waiting period. I can, however, list other services such as my databases and S3 buckets.

[aws cli failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfxXY.png)
[VS toolkit failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4CeE.png)

I have tried creating a new VM with the same results. I've disabled windows firewall altogether, allowed all traffic through the security group and have VPC endpoints for my subnet (ssm, ec2messages, lambda, ec2).

I have no trouble connecting to the lambda service through my own computer. On the VM, I have modified the .aws/credentials file to match the one on my computer for both the admin and current user but I still can't connect. This tells me that the problem isn't related to my access key credentials.

I'm reaching the end of the troubleshooting options I can think of so any help would be very much appreciated!

---

Update: using telnet, I cannot connect to lambda.ap-southeast-2 but I can connect to s3.ap-southeast-2 and lambda.ap-southeast-1. It seems lambda.ap-southeast-2 is being blocked somewhere but it isn't windows firewall because it's off and the same problem happens on Ubuntu VMs.

In the VPC Management Console, I haven't set up any firewalls under network or dns filewalls and my network ACL allows all traffic.

Comment: If you're encountering these issues on the EC2 instance (but not using your own access key credentials), then it may be worth double-checking the permissions assigned to the instance profile attached to EC2, that is, the role associated with the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried using the same access key on the ec2 instance as on my own PC but I'm still having the same issues. For my instance's IAM role, I added the AWS Managed policy 'AWSLambda_FullAccess' but this hasn't helped either. 

Just a note, with each change I have restarted the machine, just to make sure.

Comment: Another thing to verify is that the region is specified in the request or (if you're using a profile with the aws cli) that it's specified in the .aws/credentials file, i.e. `region=ap-southeast-2`

Comment: To elaborate: within the profile (can be default if it's the only one) within .aws/credentials: `[default]
aws_access_key_id=***
aws_secret_access_key=***
region=ap-southeast-2
output=json`

Comment: And if that doesn't help, there's some other potential steps you can take for a similar issue: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-could-not-connect-endpoint-url/

Comment: Following the article you posted, I tried: 
  telnet lambda.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 443
But I received "Could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed"
It looks like I'm being blocked from accessing the IP but telnet lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com 443 and even telnet lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 443 connect.
I tried connecting via a ubuntu VM and had the same issue so it isn't windows.

Comment: And your region is correctly configured as this is quite often the cause for this issue with other AWS service endpoints?

Comment: I've double-checked that the region is correct and the other services in that region are fine. Just lambda that's giving me the issue.